# Visual Studio Code "Go To Definition" in HTML does not work

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

**I'm using VS Code Version 1.51.1.**

When I would like to jump between the **Java Script** Functions inside my Project with the Go To Definition option or with the Shortcut `Option + Left Click` (Mac OS) Everything works fine.

[image: Between my JS Files]

But when I would like to do the same in my HTML file in the same project it doesn't work.

[image: Call in HTML]

**Question**: **Why isn't it possible to use the go to definition functionality in the HTML files?**
Is there a solution without the usage of Angular?

Note: I don't use Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Angular Language Service` for that it provides a feature for `Go To definition` for HTML files.

[***LINK to Angular Language Service***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't use Angular in my project, so I don't have a "Angular Template"